# Realm Save Double but float

Tags: realm, coordinate

I want to save Coordinate format in after decimal point 6 digit. ( I don't know how to describe in English, forgive me please )

ex: (25.123456, 123.123456) shows in picture in the bottom url.

But in realm browser(picture in the bottom) it save like

ex: (25.123, 123.123) also shows in picture in the bottom url.

Just 3 digit after decimal point. It is totally different position when it appear on map compare with my position.

My Realm Model with coordinate is Double, but when it saved in realm database. It became Float. I am not sure is this a certain problem I face.

Please help. Thanks for you time review my question.

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXvH1.jpg)

[realm browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TP4mD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a [display issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/issues/126) only. The Realm Browser formats floating point values to show only three digits after the decimal point. If you hold your mouse pointer over the value, you'll see a tooltip showing the full value of the field.